# $\lim_{z\rightarrow{0}}z\operatorname{Log}(z-1)=0$ (complex) - not sure if it is correct

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm doubting if my following argument for $\lim_{z\rightarrow{0}}z\operatorname{Log}(z-1)=0$ is correct.

( $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is here the principal Logarithm that is defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

I know we can't make use of $(\lim_{z\rightarrow{0}}z)(\lim_{z\rightarrow{0}}\operatorname{Log}(z-1))$ because $\lim_{z\rightarrow{0}}\operatorname{Log}(z-1)$ does not exist.

So I used the following version of the complex squeeze theorem. If $f(z)\rightarrow0$ as $z\rightarrow0$ and $\operatorname{Log}(z-1)$ is bounded on a deleted neighbourhood around $z=0$. Then we have that $\lim_{z\rightarrow{0}}z\operatorname{Log}(z-1)=0$. Now is it true that $\operatorname{Log}(z-1)$ is bounded on a deleted neighbourhood around $z=0$? Because $\operatorname{Log}(z-1)$ is not defined on let's say $(-1-\epsilon,-1+\epsilon)$ for anny $\epsilon>0$ as $z\rightarrow0$. Can we still speak of a deleted neighbourhood?

Answer (score 0):

You defined $\log$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$. Consider $\log (-1 + it)$ and $\log (-1 - it)$. Compute their limit as $t \to 0$. They should be different, so the limit does not exist

Comment: Yes that's true but we $t\log(-1+it)$ and $t\log(-1-it)$ do go both to $0$ as $t\rightarrow{0}$. (and where we have $t>0$)

Comment: Yes. Didn't see the $z$ before your $\log$ sorry !
Thus I would say that if $z$ is small enough, then  $|\log(-1 + z)| = |i\pi| + o(|z|)$, thus multiplying by $z$ will give the answer